# Run MPI program on desktop?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mpi, desktop

I created a simple Hello World program to test MPI like described by [Microsoft](http:////https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/windowshpc/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program)  Code is:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello");
    int node;
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Get the rank of the process
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &node);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from node %d\n",node);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Programs compiles without error:
[image]

But in order to get the program running i need smpd manager and mpiexec which is not part of the ms-mpi installation. And as my computer is running with windows 10 i'm unable to install Microsoft HPC. Is there a way to get a mpi program running on a desktop with several threads?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the Microsoft HPC Pack needed to run MPI programs on desktops but the [Microsoft HPC Pack SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cc853440(v=vs.85)) . Slight but important difference.

Comment: That sounds strange. An SDK is a Software **Development** Kit. You don't need those at runtime. And the SDK explicitly points to **HPC Pack Client Utilities** for the runtime.

Comment: As i'm new to MPI, i can only tell you that it worked after installing the SDK, but not without.